# Joomla site moving error

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to move a site from www.mysite.com/demo to www.mysite.com. I have moved all all the files into the new location. I didnt changed anything in configuration.php sice I am using the same domine. After moving I am getting:

1. Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL. 
   and

2.Fatal error: Call to a member function enqueueMessage() on a non-object in /*****/****/public_html/demo/libraries/joomla/error/error.php on line 480

What should I need to fix this error? Please help.

Comment: you need to move the database too

Comment: why ? I am using the same domain. Just moved it from demo folder to the root. The database details in configuration file is correct

Comment: did you set up the log path and tmp path ? there is no chance to show mysql error when it on same domain. check [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website) too

Comment: please take a look on [link](http://mrspencer.com/demo/index.php). I am sure the database details are correct and not changed. I have also updated the cache and temp paths

Comment: I am geting different errors when I refresh the same page. Please check [here](http://mrspencer.com/demo/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend installing [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html) then simply make a backup of your site.  Once the backup completes, there will be a JPA file to download.  Download and upload this file to your new location (root) where you want to move the installation to.

Then download the Akeeba Kickstart from the same download page and upload the downloaded files to the new location (root) and navigate to www.mysite.com/kickstart.php

After that simply follow the steps.  It is very easy.